# to_number() function --- the 'format' parameter

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

can anyone explain how the "format" optional paramater works in to_number() function?

Two Examples:

***WORKS***
select to_number('8aae3a73a9a43ee6b04dfd986fe9d136', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');

***DOES NOT WORK***
select to_number('kittens', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');

Comment: "works", meaning what?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentation link that will help you understand the format models :
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql-format-models.html

Answer (score 1):

```
'aae3a73a9a43ee6b04dfd986fe9d136' is a valid hexadecimal number
'kittens' is not a valid hexadecimal number
```

Try this

```
select hex_encode('kittens',0);--'6b697474656e73'
select to_number('6b697474656e73', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your working example, the input is a valid hexadecimal, so the TO_NUMBER() function works.  'kittens' is not a valid hexadecimal.